# ember controllers: computed property not recalculating off injected property

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a custom ClockService object that i inject into my application controller like so (taken from [ember js cookbook](http://emberjs.com/guides/cookbook/working_with_objects/continuous_redrawing_of_views/)):

```
App.ClockService = Em.Object.extend({
  pulse: Ember.computed.oneWay('_seconds').readOnly(),
  tick: function () {
    var clock = this;
    Ember.run.later(function () {
      var seconds = clock.get('_seconds');
      if (typeof seconds === 'number') {
        clock.set('_seconds', seconds + (1/4));
      }
    }, 250);
  }.observes('_seconds').on('init'),
  _seconds: 0
});

Ember.Application.initializer({
  name: 'clockServiceInitializer',
  initialize: function(container, application) {
    container.register('clock:service', App.ClockService);
    application.inject('controller:application', 'clock', 'clock:service');
  }
});
```

And i create a computed property in the Application Controller from the pulse property in clock service:

```
App.ApplicationController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
    currentTime: function(){
        return moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a');
    }.property('clock.pulse')
});
```

The timestamp (using [Momentjs](http://momentjs.com)) is viewable in the main application on screen but it does not redraw with the pulse. Am i doing something wrong?

**UPDATE:**

Applying Kingpins update below, I now have the following working solution:

```
App.ApplicationController = Em.Controller.extend({
setTime: function() {
    var time = moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a');
    this.set('currentTime', time);
    Em.run.later(this, this.setTime, .9999);
}.on('init'),

currentTime: undefined
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're never fetching `pulse` so Ember is never computing it, and as such is never seeing it change...

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/kajuqeja/1/edit

You could also use the crazy `_seconds` item, and since it's being set it will update

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/kajuqeja/2/edit

Either way, this seems like a ton of overhead, firing a property change every 1/4 second etc.  If you really want to keep this in the page I'd up that to .99 second, and maybe ditch the whole clock service and set up a simple `Ember.run.later` for your time update.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/kajuqeja/3/edit

Comment: Thanks for the tip, and +1 for the overhead heads up (no pun intended).

Comment: I have one question though, I wish for the application route to administrate a model as well and simply using Em.Controller forbids me from doing so, How would i avoid getting a `Error: Assertion Failed: Error: Assertion Failed: Cannot delegate set('currentTime', April 28th 2014, 5:37:52 pm) to the 'content' property of object proxy <App.ApplicationController:ember1239>: its 'content' is undefined.` my applicationRoute already returns a model

Comment: turns out the `currentTime: undefined` was the problem. was there a reason you made it undefined in the jsbin?

Comment: nah, I was just putting an empty property in there, and made it `Em.Controller` since there was no model backing it in my example.  I could have left the property off.  Since you're application controller is backed by a model, `ObjectController` is appropriate, and the property would have to be defined or Ember will get mad at you, due to it trying to find where the property exists, and when it looks on the model it won't find it, and it will yell (as you saw).